# Host application server in windows service or IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, architecture, windows-services, servicestack

I'm starting new project for my client. It will be kind of big system with web UI (many, many users) + desktop UI (few users).

I was wondering. Should I host my all logic in Windows services or IIS?

The application can do many operations in background (imports, exports, preparing data for reports). The web client (ASP.NET MVC) and desktop client (and other clients) will be connecting with my service through [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/)/WCF.

Answer (score 2):

### Running Background Services in the same ASP.NET application

If you use [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) you can host your [Web service APIs and Background Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview) in the same ASP.NET Web Application. ServiceStack has some nice support for this story where if you have an `IMessageService` registered, all OneWay Async HTTP calls are automatically deferred and published to the registered MQ Service (E.g. For Redis MQ, the Request DTO gets published in the Services MQ Inbox).

### Running Background Services in different ASP.NET applications

As deployments of ASP.NET hosts is easier to do with an ASP.NET application than a Windows Services, at [StackOverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) we've opted to split the BackOffice services into a separate ASP.NET Web Application (that's not publicly available).

For **One-Way** messages, the Internet facing Careers website drops Request DTOs into Redis which gets processed by [ServiceStack's Redis MQ Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis). For normal reply services we're able to re-use the Request DTO and call ServiceStack Web Services directly using one of the [typed C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview).

One of the benefits of using ServiceStack is the [built-in Messaging API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis) is able to re-use your existing Web Services so we're able to get the [advantages of messaging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services) without having to develop a specific MQ-only service.

#### Ensuring the MQ Service is always running

As running background threads is a bit more volatile in an ASP.NET host, we add this in our Global.asax to call `mqHost.Start()` at the end of every request which will Start the MQ Server main thread if it was killed for any reason:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If the MQ Host goes down for whatever reason, restart it
    if (appHost == null) return;
    var mqHost = appHost.TryResolve<IMessageService>();
    if (mqHost != null)
        mqHost.Start();
}
```

This is normally No-Op but if the Master background thread was killed for any reason it will start it back up again.

#### Running Background Services in a Windows Service

Running it a Windows Service is the probably the ideal environment for background services since it's not subject to AppDomain restarts and ASP.NET request limits. Deploying and debugging Windows Services are harder and they're not cross platform so I generally avoid them unless they're needed. But if you want to go down this route you should check out ServiceStack's Windows Service demo projects:

- [Razor Rockstars Windows Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WinService)
- [Windows Service Starter Template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost)

Answer (score 1):

I do:

Business logic accessed from WCF Services (http,tcp, whatever your requirements are )

Windows services used for heavy background tasks with multi-threads or not( parse huge xml documents, extract big data from file, time consuming system integraction etc etc etc... )

UI to deal with light background tasks requested and responsed through http ( using asp.net mvc consuming WCF services or doing UI Stuff)